# Spivak, Ch. 23, 6b: $f$ cont on interval around $0$, $a_n=f(1/n)$. Prove if $f'(0)$ exists, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, then $f'(0)=0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The following are the first two items from a problem in Ch. 23, "Infinite Series", from Spivak's *Calculus*

> 6. Let $f$ be a continuous function on an interval around $0$, and let
>    $a_n=f(1/n)$ (for large enough $n$).
>
> (a) Prove that if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges then
> $f(0)=0$.
>
> (b) Prove that if $f'(0)$ exists and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$
> converges, then $f'(0)=0$.

My question is about item (b).

The solution manual simply says

> If
>
> $$0\neq c =\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}
>  \frac{a_n}{1/n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} na_n$$
>
> then by the limit comparison test, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ wouldn't
> converge, since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n$ doesn't

First of all, let me try to understand this solution.

It seems to be basically writing $a_n=(na_n)\cdot \frac{1}{n}$ and arguing that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left [(na_n)\cdot \frac{1}{n}\right ]$ diverges if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (na_n)=c\neq 0$. Is this a correct interpretation?

If so, how do we conclude that $f'(0)=0$?

Comment: If $f'(0) $ exists, we have $f'(0) =\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(1/n)-f(0)}{1/n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(1/n)}{1/n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}nf(1/n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n$. You have shown in a) that $f(0)=0 $. You use it here. Further that $f'(0) $ exists, ensures $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n$ exists.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc What does $a_n\searrow 0$ mean exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the comment from Jochen, here is the full interpretation of what the solution manual is doing.

By assumption $f'(0)$ exists. This means the following limit exists

$$f'(0)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(1/x)-f(0)}{1/x}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(1/x)}{1/x}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} xf(1/x)$$

Assume $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} xf(1/x)=c\neq 0$.

Then,

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left [ (na_n)\cdot \frac{1}{n} \right ] = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (nf(1/n))\frac{1}{n}$$

which diverges by the limit comparison test, as follows

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{nf(1/n)\cdot \frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} nf(1/n)=c\neq 0$$

Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, then so does $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$. But this contradicts one of our initial assumptions, that $a_n$ is summable.

Hence, by proof by contradiction, we infer that

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} xf(1/x)=0$$

and thus that

$$f'(0)=0$$

Comment: Your argument is not quite correct for convergence of $\sum_na_n$ does not imply convergence of $\sum_n|a_n|$ in general. Some monotonicity implications can be derived in your problem when $c\neq0$.

Comment: Where did I assume that convergence of $\sum a_n$ implies convergence of $\sum |a_n|$?

Comment: To apply the comparison test you need to compare $\frac1n$ to $|a_n|$! The comparison test works for series with non negative terms: If $a_n,b_n\geq0$ and $c b_n\leq a_n$ for all large $N$ ($ c>0$ a constant) then $\sum_nb_n$ converges if $\sum_na_n$ does; conversely ...

Comment: If we apply the comparison test for $|a_n|$ we obtain the result that $\sum |a_n|$ is convergent. Hence $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent, and thus convergent, correct?

Comment: In your problem, the fact that $\sum_na_n$ converges along with the assumption that $c>0$ (or $c<0$) implies that $\sum_n|a_n|$ converges. This allows you to use comparison test to arise to a contradiction. I added a posting, but I still leave some "why?"s or you.

Comment: We can split into two cases. In case 1, $c>0$.  Then for $n$ large enough, $f(1/x)$ is positive since $xf(1/x)$ must be near $c>0$. We can apply the limit comparison test with $1/n$ as in the answer above. In case 2, $c<0$. Then for $n$ large enough, $f(1/x)$ is negative because $xf(1/x)$ must be near $c<0$. If we apply the limit comparison test with $\{a_n\}$ and $-1/n$, then we have $\lim \frac{nf(1/n)\cdot 1/n}{-1/n}=\lim [-nf(1/n)]=-c\neq 0$. Since $-1/n$ diverges, so does $a_n$. What is the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140302/discussion-between-oliver-diaz-and-evianpring).

Answer (score 0):

If $c=\lim_n na_n\neq0$ then for some $N$ large enough $|na_n|>|c|/2$ for all $n\geq N$. Hence
$$\frac{|c|}{2}\frac1n\leq  |a_n|,\qquad n\geq N$$

If $c\neq0$ then there is $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|h|<\delta$, then
$$c-\frac{|c|}{2}<\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}<\frac{|c|}{2}+c$$

There are two cases:

1. If $f'(0)=c>0$ there is $M\geq N$ such that  $a_n<0$ (why?) for all $n\geq M$.  As $\sum_na_n$ converges, so does $\sum_n(-a_n)$ and thus $\sum_n|a_n|$ converges (at most finitely many terms $a_n$ are positive).
2. If $f'(c)=c<0$, then there is $M\geq N$ such that $a_n>0$ (why?) for all $n\geq M$. Hence $\sum_n|a_n|$ converges (at most finitely many terms $a_n$ are negative).

Putting this together, yields that if $c\neq0$, then $\sum_n\frac1n$ converges which is not possible.

Comment: Did not really understand this solution. If $c>0$, for example, we have that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty} na_n = c>0$. There is an interval $(0,\delta)$ in which $f$ is increasing. In this interval $f(1/n)$ is decreasing from some positive value down to 0 in the limit. Where do you see $a_n<0$?

Comment: That $a_n<0$ for all $n$ large enough follows from the fact that for some $\delta<0$, if $0<h<\delta$, then $\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}<\frac{c}{2}<0$.

Comment: @evianpring: Hopefully the argument is clearer now. I removed monotonicity now which magic have obscure a few things.