# Spivak, Ch. 23, Problem 6c

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, proof-explanation

The following are the first three items from a problem in Ch. 23, "Infinite Series", from Spivak's *Calculus*

> 6. Let $f$ be a continuous function on an interval around $0$, and let
>    $a_n=f(1/n)$ (for large enough $n$).
>
> (a) Prove that if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges then
> $f(0)=0$.
>
> (b) Prove that if $f'(0)$ exists and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$
> converges, then $f'(0)=0$.
>
> (c) Prove that if $f''(0)$ exists and $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

[I've previously asked about item (b)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4566438/spivak-ch-23-6b-f-cont-on-interval-around-0-a-n-f1-n-prove-if-f?noredirect=1#comment9608198_4566438), but this question is about item (c).

**The solution manual simply says**

> By Taylor's Theorem, $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}f''(0)x^2+R(x)$ where
> $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{R(x)}{x^2}=0$. So
>
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{1/n^2}=\frac{1}{2}f''(0)$$
>
> and the limit comparison test can be used.

**Here is my understanding of this solution in more steps**

By Taylor's Theorem and our assumption that $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, we have

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}f''(0)x^2+R(x)$$

where $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{R(x)}{x^2}=0$

Then,

$$a_n=f(1/n)=\frac{f''(0)}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{n^2}+R(1/n)$$

Now, since $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{R(1/n)}{(1/n)^2}=0$, we have

$$\frac{a_n}{1/n^2}=\frac{f''(0)}{2}+\frac{R(1/n)}{1/n^2}$$

We can use the limit comparison test with $\{a_n\}$ and $\{1/n^2\}$ as follows

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{1/n^2} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left [ \frac{f''(0)}{2}+\frac{R(1/n)}{1/n^2} \right ]$$

$$=\frac{f''(0)}{2}=c$$

If $f''(0)\neq 0$ then $c\neq 0$ and by the limit comparison test since $\{1/n^2\}$ converges then so does $\{a_n\}$.

It seems that I have used an additional assumption, namely that $f''(0)\neq 0$.

Was this assumption missing from the problem statement, or is there a way to use the limit comparison test without needing this assumption above?

Comment: $c \ne 0$ is not needed. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{1/n^2} = 0$ implies the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test#One-sided_version

Comment: @MartinR Still seems like we still need to make some assumptions that aren't present in the problem statement. For example, do we know that $a_n \geq 0$? We do know that since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{1/n^2}$ exists and equals $\frac{f''(0)}{2}=c$, then $\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n=c$. Now, according to the linked one-sided version of the limit comparison test, if $0\leq c<\infty$  (and $\{1/n^2\}$ is summable, which it is), then we can conclude that $\{a_n\}$ is summable. But it seems we still need the assumption on $c$ and hence on $f''(0)$, namely that it is $\geq 0$ in this case.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{1/n^2} = 0$ is equivalent to $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{|a_n|}{1/n^2} = 0$ ...

Answer (score 1):

$f''(0)=2\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(h)-f'(0)h}{h^2}$ (L'Hospital rule for example or a second order mean value theorem). Thus, there is $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|h|<\delta$, then
$$|f(h)|<(\tfrac12|f''(0)|+1)h^2$$
For all $n$ large enough, $1/n<\delta$ and so
$$|a_n|=|f(1/n)|\leq (\tfrac12|f''(0)|+1)\frac{1}{n^2}$$
The conclusion follows by comparison.